# perl search file for masked pattern, not exact string

Tags: string, perl, maskedinput

i need to find entries in a log file after certain date/time values, such as, "all the entries after Oct 18 00:00:00". currently this log file does not have the year. ultimately i need to search for all entries since the file time stamp. ["any new messages"]. So, the pattern needs to be like a mask of say, "Abc # hh:mm:ss", or in the case of a date before the 10th, "Abc ## hh:mm:ss", where Abc = Jan thru Dec, # or ## = 1-31; and hours are 24-hr time.

sample log entry, without having to give away proprietary info:

```
Oct 15 20:32:58 servername01 /opt/www/myApp/cgi-bin/script.pl[12345]: ALERT: Fatal error connecting to database.
```

searched CPAN did not find anything, maybe something is out there? anything simpler than having to search the file comparing text to arrays of the month, dates, hours, minutes, and seconds would be very helpful!!

any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: that's non trivial, especially if you're crossing month/year boundaries. e.g. `(Dec|Jan)` is going to catch 4 months, not two, because presumably those two months exist in two different years.

Comment: I don't know why this is marked as duplicate, doesn't quite match the requirements of the linked article. For my take on it see this gist; https://gist.github.com/yevrah/9b2441c544c994a1fb8e/#file-parse_log_date-pl

Comment: @dcparham np! I figured you might have missed that. It is helpful to mark the answer that solves your problem, but you also don't have to mark one if your problem isn't solved. I also agree this question is not a duplicate. The question here is how to match a timestamp and compare it to an arbitrary date. The other question answers what to do when you find a match (set a variable and print everything once the variable is set). This question will hopefully get reopened. I think harvey's link will help you. You can use `@` to tag someone in a comment so they get a notification.

Comment: Marc B - assuming i successfully get the year added, meanwhile i am faced with searching the log for dates <, =, or > certain dates. again, searching a pattern, not actual string. in human terms, "search the log for strings where there is [always this pattern:] a 3-char Mon[th] + space + date[1-31], then followed by hh:mm:ss". Grep using Perl and pump into awk command, perhaps? thx for your time!

Comment: This still looks like a duplicate of your previous question, but perhaps I just don't understand what you're asking (your wording is a little unclear). What do you mean by "mask"? Do you mean that you want to find all log entries with a timestamp greater than a given time? If so, that seems to be the same as what you asked in the last question: "i want to return all messages beginning on a date > the last time stamp". If not, please [edit your question to clarify how it is not a duplicate.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253521) Editing will automatically put it in the reopen queue.

Comment: If other users agree that it truly is not a duplicate, they can vote to reopen the question. Make sure your edit *clearly* shows the difference between the two questions, however. Myself and Miller both thought this was a duplicate, but your description is not exactly clear, so I'm willing to change my viewpoint.